# Does the periodic and $C^1$ class $f$ satisfy Hölder condition for all $\alpha>0$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, periodic-functions

Let $\mathscr C^\alpha$ be a set of functions that satisfy $\alpha$- Holder condition, i.e.,
$$\mathscr C^\alpha:=\{f : \mathbb R\to \mathbb C \mid \exists M>0\ ;\ |f(x)-f(y)|\leqq M |x-y|^\alpha \ \mathrm{for \ all} \ x,y \in \mathbb R \}$$ for $\alpha >0.$

I want to consider whether [$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is periodic and  $C^1 \Rightarrow f\in \mathscr C^\alpha$ for all $\alpha >0$] holds or not.

---

**For $0<\alpha \leqq 1.$**

Since $f$ is periodic and continuous, $f$ is bounded and Lipschitz continuous.

So, there exists $L, C>0$ s.t. $|f(x)|\leqq C$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqq L|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

Let $M=\max\{2C, L\}$.

Fix $x,y\in \mathbb R$.

If $|x-y|\geqq 1$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqq |f(x)|+|f(y)|\leqq 2C \leqq 2C|x-y|^\alpha \leqq M|x-y|^\alpha.$

If $|x-y|<1$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqq L|x-y|\leqq L|x-y|^\alpha\leqq M|x-y|^\alpha.$

Thus $f \in \mathscr C^\alpha.$

---

But what about $\alpha >1$ ?

For $|x-y|\geqq 1,$ the same way can be applied, but for $|x-y|<1$, I couldn't show $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqq M|x-y|^\alpha.$

What can I do for $\alpha >1 $ ? Or, isn't the statement true for $\alpha>1$ ?

Comment: $\alpha > 1$ Holder implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you. For $\alpha >1$, $f(x)=\sin x$ is a counter example. @paulblartmathcop

Comment: If $\alpha > 1$ then divide both sides of the inequality by $|x - y|$. The left hand side becomes a difference quotient. Take the limit as $y \to x$ of both sides. The left hand side then becomes $|f'(x)|$ whereas the right hand side becomes $\lim_{y \to x} M |x-y|^{\alpha - 1} = 0$.

Comment: So $f'(x)=0$ thus $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yup, that's right.